# Research collaboration: past snapshots of Yoroi/Adapools pool rankings

Tags: stake-pool, staking, yoroi

We are an MIT-based team doing research on the evolution of the Cardano ecosystem. We are analyzing delegations and we find the current snapshot of Yoroi/Adapools rankings at

- https://js.adapools.org/pools.json
- https://a.adapools.org/yoroi-api/
- https://adapools.yoroiwallet.com/

We are wondering if anyone in the community has saved * *past* * snapshots from either one of these sources. These will be immensely useful for our research.

Thank you. We'll discuss our research once it's completed and we hope to contribute to the progress of the community. Please feel free to reach out at `jiageng@mit.edu`.

---

Related questions about the Cardano ecosystem:

- [Why do Binance stake pools pledge nothing?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/why-do-binance-stake-pools-pledge-nothing)
- [Rising trend in blocks missing: what could be the reason? Should we worry?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/rising-trend-in-blocks-missing-what-could-be-the-reason-should-we-worry)

Comment: I do not have any such snapshots. However I think all of these rank pools on the same data, which is likely to be stored in `cardano-db-sync` . If you can request information about the methodology these sites use, then it should be possible to recreate pool rankings for past epochs using the `db-sync` data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not fit the typical Q&A format. The call to get in contact privately via email is not something that will be beneficial to the users here on the SE. While it is an endeavor that may be supported by the community, the research itself is not even explained. Other avenues may be better, but I do not think with our current guidelines, this "question" should remain open.